# Numpy arrays indexing/assignment question, code that looks like it should work, doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have the following array:

```
c = np.array([[1,2,3],
             [4,5,6],
             [7,8,9]])
```

I want to change the 2nd column values that are greater than 2 to 99, and the following boolean assignment works for that purpose:

```
c[c[:,1] > 2,1] = 99
```

However, from my understanding, the following code should also be able to achieve the same:

```
c[c[:,1] > 2] = 99
```

Yet it does not? Anyone able to illuminate why that is??

[image]

The first code in the above image shows the wrong code, and the 2nd image shows the right code with the right effect. I can't wrap my head at all around why the first doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c[:,1]` will return a vector that contains booleans. For each row in `c` a boolean that specifies if the value in the second column is larger than two, so:

```
>>> c[:,1] > 2
array([False,  True,  True])
```

This indeed is correct:

```
c[:,1] > 2  |     c
----------------------
False       |  1  2  3
True        |  4  5  6
True        |  7  8  9
```

So now we have a boolean mask, and that means we are going to assign *all* the columns of all the rows where it is `True`. So that means that the items in boldface here will be updated:

```
c[:,1] > 2  |     c
----------------------
False       |  1  2  3
True        |  4  5  6
True        |  7  8  9
```

Indeed, when we process this, we obtain:

```
>>> c[c[:,1] > 2] = 99
>>> c
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [99, 99, 99],
       [99, 99, 99]])
```

If you however specify `c[np.array(False, True, True), 1]`, you only assign to the second column, so then the items that will be updated are:

```
c[:,1] > 2  |     c
----------------------
False       |  1  2  3
True        |  4  5  6
True        |  7  8  9
```

This again holds when we process this:

```
>>> c[c[:,1] > 2, 1] = 99
>>> c
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 99,  6],
       [ 7, 99,  9]])
```

Comment: Thank you mate, that helped me visualize it perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down: `c[c[:,1] > 2] = 99`

starting from the inside: `c[:,1]` means "for every sub-array, take the item at position 1"

This gives us `c[[2,5,8] > 2] = 99`

Five and eight are both greater than 2.

So now we have `c[False, True, True] = 99` -- which is only indexing into the first sub-levels, so we leave the first row alone (since it corresponds to False) and change all of the second two rows to True.

The interpretation of the second, correct code is better visualized with parentheses.

```
c[(c[:,1] > 2), 1] = 99
```

We already translated the first part, so the simplified expression becomes:

```
c[(False, True, True), 1] = 99
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it helps a lot to visually maintain a picture in mind of just where False/True Boolean indexes are at any point!! This finally caused it to click for me, and now that it has, I also realize in hindsight how I could have worked backwards from the previous code to figure out what was going on!